Equation in greatest integer of x
I have tried by letting x = n + p < 0, where n is a negative integer and p is a real number where |p|<1.
When p<0, the greatest integer is n-1 (e.g. -3 - 0.75 —> -4). So,
8(n+p) - 7(n-1) = 4
p = (-3-n)/8
So -3-n <0, and n > -3
So the sum is -2 - 1/8 - 1 - 1/4 = -3.375
When p>0, the greatest integer is simply n (e.g. -3 + 0.75 —> -3). So,
8(n+p) - 7(n) = 4
p = (4-n)/8
So n<4 which doesn’t really help
The actual answer is -3.75, and I don’t see where my logic doesn’t hold up
Would like some hints or solution to the question


Let $x = n+p$ where $0\le p < 1$ so that $[x] = n$. We then have the equation:
$$ 8(n+p) - 7n = 4 $$
$$ n+8p = 4 $$
$$ 8p = 4-n $$
Then noting that $n \le -1$ in order for $x$ to be negative we have that $4-n \ge 5$. Now because $p<1$ we have $8p < 8$. With the fact that $4-n$ must be an integer we have that $4-n$ is 5, 6, or 7. Hence $n=-1,-2,-3$. Can you take it from here?
